# Colocar foto de perfil no Nav_Header

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Tenho uma dúvida na criação de um App.

Preciso colocar a foto de perfil do usuário na minha Nav_Header_Tela_Princial.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tenho uma tela de perfil, porém preciso usar a mesma imagem da tela de perfil do usuário para a minha NAV.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tela de perfil está funcionando corretamente, já consigo salvar a imagem, porém preciso apenas usar a mesma Uri na outra tela.

Eu ainda não consegui criar nada de código pois não tenho ideia do que pesquisar. 
Preciso de uma luz de como realizar isso.

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("foto", resultUri.toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, TelaPrincipalActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);

    edtNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    edtPhoneField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);

    imgProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfileImage);

    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID);

    getUserInfo();

    imgProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
```

Essa seria a Activity que deve receber os dados da Uri.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_principal);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    String foto = bundle.getString("foto");

    btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnTest);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openBtnTest();
        }
    });

    edtSearch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);

    edtSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            search();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito rasa. Sua duvida é como recuperar a imagem? Como apresenta-la dentro do `ImageView`?

Comment: Se caso for para como recuperar a imagem, você deverá especificar onde está salvando ela. Assim, fica mais facil de te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

**Se o que você deseja é usar a foto do banco de dados para exibir** na Nav_Header_Foto você vai precisar resgatar esta Url do banco de dados, e isto é feito de acordo com a sua aplicação.
 Aqui está um exemplo de como resgatar um valor do banco de dados (neste caso Firebase RealTime Database) para exibir ao carregar a activity (carregamento no método OnCreate da activity):

[getDados](https://github.com/JhowRaul/LoginFirebase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/opet/loginfirebase/Initial.java) Também tem o exemplo de criar usuário.

Agora, **se deseja apenas passar a informação de uma activity para outra** e suponho que saiba alguma coisa sobre manipular os elementos da View (os *R.id.findViewById* e etc...)

Você pode enviar os dados que quiser através do **Bundle**.

É só adaptar este exemplo em algum evento na class de sua activity, onde urlFoto é a variável já com a url e o intent é usado para fazer a transição entre as activities:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("foto", urlfoto.toString());

 Intent intent = new Intent(activityAtual.this, proximaActivity.class);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);

 startActivity(intent);
```

Agora na proximaActivity.java você resgata os valores com o seguinte código:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

 String foto = bundle.getString("foto");
```

É só usar o seu url e setar no elemento da View que desejar.

Comment: A ideia é só passar a informação da minha SettingsActivity que possui um imageView com a foto de perfil do usuário para minha ActivityPrincipal que tbm possui um ImageView, porém esse só vai receber os dados.

Comment: Para isso você deve pegar o Url do banco de dados e colocar no ImageView como eu havia dito na resposta, por favor, esclareça qual a dificuldade para que possamos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Então Jhow tentei fazer como você mencionou, mas o aplicativo da crash.
Eu preciso criar novos métodos ou é só jogar no OnCreate ?
Editei minha pergunta e adicionei o que você mencionou, por gentileza validar se seria assim mesmo.